# error calling managed code from unmanaged in C++/CLI

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, interop, unmanaged, managed

I'm writing a "driver" for a program, the driver communicates with some devices on network. I already have C# software working with the devices, so the plan is to reuse code.
So the driver dll is really an interop between program and and already availible assemblies, it's written in C++/CLI. The program calls methods described in interface, the interop dll calls C# code, that is how I see it.

I implement methods to be called by program using `#pragma unmanaged`

```
DeviceSearch::DeviceSearch(IDeviceSearchHandler* handler):m_handler(handler)
{
    ManagedWrapper mw;
    mw.Init();
}
```

ManagedWrapper is implemented in managed code, obviously

```
void ManagedWrapper::Init()
{

    //some code
}
```

However, the problem rises here. If the Init() is empty or calls methods/classes defined in C++, it's working ok. However, if I try to call the C# code (which is referenced using #using , where Facade.dll is the C# dll which performs some functions), I get  access violation exception right when mw.Init() is called, not even within it.

Am I missing something really obvious I should do to make the interop work? Most information in the net just tells that it should "just work"

Comment: (1) Make sure mixed-mode debugging is enabled.  (2) Move all the code inside `Init` to a private helper method.  If now Init starts running successfully, and crashes on the call to the helper method, then one of the C# types you are using failed to JIT.  If it still fails at the call to the (almost empty) `Init` method, then your native code has corrupted the .NET runtime engine.

Comment: It still fails. I've also implemented the solution described in the answer, but still the same failure. How to diagnose the corruption and get rid of it? Or is it better to use another method of interop?

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:

According to [How can i use a C# dll in a Win32 C++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446404/how-can-i-use-a-c-dll-in-a-win32-c-project)

"Define an abstract interface class in your native C++ code, then create a concrete subclass inside the managed C++ DLL. Call into your C# objects in the method implementations.

Finally, export a factory function that will instantiate the implementation class and return a base-class pointer that your native code can use."