# Compiling and using a function written in C# in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++

Is there a way to include a piece of C# code in a Visual C++ project?

Alternatively, can a compiled C# program be called from a Visual C++ program.
Information will need to be passed to the C# program, and the output read from the VC++ program.

Thank you in advance.
a.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i use a C# dll in a Win32 C++ project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446404/how-can-i-use-a-c-sharp-dll-in-a-win32-c-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a C# library that you can include in your C++ project.

Creating the library is the easy part, including it into your C++ project requires an managed interop wrapper DLL. Because most users want to include their C++ code into their C# code there are a lot of tutorials how to do that. But fortunately there already is an answer for that on Stack Overflow: [How can i use a C# dll in a Win32 C++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446404/how-can-i-use-a-c-sharp-dll-in-a-win32-c-project)